# How to convert this CURL request to VB.NET code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, api, curl

I am trying to upload a file to MixCloud using their API. In their documentation following curl request is the only example. I want this request to convert to VB.net WebRequest or other method. I need it in VB.net language. I tried everything including HttpResponseMessage but it reruns an error like bad request. Please help.

```
curl -F mp3=@upload.mp3 \
     -F "name=API Upload" \
     -F "tags-0-tag=Test" \
     -F "tags-1-tag=API" \
     -F "sections-0-chapter=Introduction" \
     -F "sections-0-start_time=0" \
     -F "sections-1-artist=Artist Name" \
     -F "sections-1-song=Song Title" \
     -F "sections-1-start_time=10" \
     -F "description=My test upload" \
     https://api.mixcloud.com/upload/?access_token=INSERT_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE
```

Comment: https://curl.olsh.me/ followed by tidying it up on https://rextester.com/MZPEK64527 and then https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/ seems to do the trick

Comment: Post your actual code, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much @Martheen I will try it.

Comment: In order to help others quickly find the solution when they have similar questions, you can consider sharing your solution in answer and then [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @XingyuZhao thanks for the tip. I added the solution in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added VB.net code created using the method mentioned by @Martheen and I found the solution. Also I had to add

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

To allow TLS

This is final working code

```
Public Async Sub Upload(username As String, fileName As String, songTitle As String, description As String, accessToken As String)

    Try
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Using httpClient = New HttpClient()
            Using request = New HttpRequestMessage(New HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.mixcloud.com/upload/?access_token=" & accessToken)
                Dim multipartContent = New MultipartFormDataContent()
                multipartContent.Add(New ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)), "mp3", Path.GetFileName(fileName))
                multipartContent.Add(New StringContent(songTitle), "name")
                multipartContent.Add(New StringContent(description), "description")
                request.Content = multipartContent
                Dim response = Await httpClient.SendAsync(request)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.InnerException.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```